# Carbon Is there a way to get date by concatenating time and day of the week

Tags: laravel, datetime

I've searched through but most stackoverflow are asking for date and time.

I'm trying to create a datetime using an existing Day Eg. `Monday` and StartTime Eg. `09:00`
I've googled around but doesn't seem really helpful. Most are using createfromtimestamp which concatenates date and time but i don't have an existing date.

I want to concatenate them together together to get a specific timestamp.

Comment: need more information, such as are you trying to create a string? and how many start times? or are you trying for when the request is hit at that current time? e.g. monday-7:36 or are you wanting to map over each starting hour of a day and create strings for each day like monday-12:00 monday-1:00 monday-2:00 so on..

Answer (score 2):

Carbon's parse method accepts the same input as strtotime

```
$data = Carbon::parse("Monday 09:00");
echo $data->format('D, j-M-Y H:i:s');
```

Output

```
Mon, 3-Aug-2020 09:00:00
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php